# Difference of two javascript arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like this:

```
owners: [
  {
    userID: "58c4d7ac",
    username: "John.Doe",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "John.Doe@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "68c4d7ac",
    username: "User2.Name2",
    firstName: "User2",
    lastName: "Name2",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  }
]
```

```
users: [
  {
    userID: "58c4d7ac",
    username: "John.Doe",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "John.Doe@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "68c4d7ac",
    username: "User2.Name2",
    firstName: "User2",
    lastName: "Name2",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "88c4d7ac",
    username: "User3.Name3",
    firstName: "User3",
    lastName: "Name3",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  }
]
```

I would like to get an array of users which contains only the elements which are not in the owners array.

I tried different approaches. Finally, I ended up with the solution:

```
const usersItems = users.map(user => {
    // Check whether the user is already an owner
    if (owners.findIndex(owner => owner.userID === user.userID) === -1) {
        return  owner
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});

console.log(usersItems);

// Filter out all items which are null
const newUsersItems = usersItems.filter(user => {
    if (user) return user;
});

console.log(usersItems);
```

To me, it doesn't' look like a clean solution. Is there a cleaner and easier way to do this? As a result, I would like to have:

```
newUsers: [
  {
    userID: "88c4d7ac",
    username: "User3.Name3",
    firstName: "User3",
    lastName: "Name3",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get rid of your `map` and just use the filter, (that's exactly what filter is for) somthing like

```
const filtered = users.filter(user => {
    // Check whether the user is already an owner
   return owners.findIndex(owner => owner.userID === user.userID) === -1

});
```

would probably work

Comment: Worth noting that if performance on large datasets matters to you Shidersz answer below is worth looking at

Answer (score 2):

First you can create a **[Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** with the `userID's` of the `owners` array, and then you can use **[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** on the `users` array to filter the users whose `userID` does not belong to the previous created set.

```js
const owners = [
  {userID: "58c4d7ac", username: "John.Doe", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "John.Doe@acme.com"},
  {userID: "68c4d7ac", username: "User2.Name2", firstName: "User2", lastName: "Name2", email: "dh@acme.com"}
];

const users = [
  {userID: "58c4d7ac", username: "John.Doe", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "John.Doe@acme.com"},
  {userID: "68c4d7ac", username: "User2.Name2", firstName: "User2", lastName: "Name2", email: "dh@acme.com"},
  {userID: "88c4d7ac", username: "User3.Name3", firstName: "User3", lastName: "Name3", email: "dh@acme.com"}
];

let ownerIdsSet = new Set(owners.map(x => x.userID));
let res = users.filter(x => !ownerIdsSet.has(x.userID));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

> But why to construct a Set first?

In summary, it will improve the performance of the filtering process, particularly if the `owners` array is large. You should note that methods like `findIndex()`, `find()` and `some()` needs to traverse the array for check to the related condition while checking if the `userID` belongs to the `Set` is a **`O(1)`** calculation. However, of course, there will be an extra overload at initialization to create the mentioned Set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) functions like this:

```js
const owners = [
  {
    userID: "58c4d7ac",
    username: "John.Doe",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "John.Doe@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "68c4d7ac",
    username: "User2.Name2",
    firstName: "User2",
    lastName: "Name2",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  }
];

const users = [
  {
    userID: "58c4d7ac",
    username: "John.Doe",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "John.Doe@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "68c4d7ac",
    username: "User2.Name2",
    firstName: "User2",
    lastName: "Name2",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  },
  {
    userID: "88c4d7ac",
    username: "User3.Name3",
    firstName: "User3",
    lastName: "Name3",
    email: "dh@acme.com"
  }
];

const result = users.filter(user => !owners.some(owner => owner.userID === user.userID));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and some

```js
const owners = [{userID:"58c4d7ac",username:"John.Doe",firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe",email:"John.Doe@acme.com"},{userID:"68c4d7ac",username:"User2.Name2",firstName:"User2",lastName:"Name2",email:"dh@acme.com"}]
const users = [{userID:"58c4d7ac",username:"John.Doe",firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe",email:"John.Doe@acme.com"},{userID:"68c4d7ac",username:"User2.Name2",firstName:"User2",lastName:"Name2",email:"dh@acme.com"},{userID:"88c4d7ac",username:"User3.Name3",firstName:"User3",lastName:"Name3",email:"dh@acme.com"}]

const newUsers = users
                .filter(({userID}) => !owners.some(({userID:ownerID})=> ownerID === userID))

console.log(newUsers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a single `.filter()` function, like so:

```js
let owners = [{userID: "58c4d7ac",username: "John.Doe",firstName: "John",lastName: "Doe",email: "John.Doe@acme.com"},{userID: "68c4d7ac",username: "User2.Name2",firstName: "User2",lastName: "Name2",email: "dh@acme.com"}];

let users = [{userID: "58c4d7ac",username: "John.Doe",firstName: "John",lastName: "Doe",email: "John.Doe@acme.com"},{userID: "68c4d7ac",username: "User2.Name2",firstName: "User2",lastName: "Name2",email: "dh@acme.com"},{userID: "88c4d7ac",username: "User3.Name3",firstName: "User3",lastName: "Name3",email: "dh@acme.com"}];

let newUsersItems = users.filter(user => owners.findIndex(owner => owner.userID === user.userID) === -1);

console.log(newUsersItems)
```

You can just use a single `.filter()` function, like so:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) function

```
    const diff = users.reduce((acc, user) => { 
      if(!owners.find(owner => owner.id === user.id){
     acc.push(user);
    }
    return acc;
     }, []);
```

to avoid use the find() function every loop you can store owner ids in a array with the map an just use includes()

```
 const ownersIds = owners.map(owner => owner.id);
 const diff = users.reduce((acc, user) => { 
   if(!ownersIds.includes(user.id){
     acc.push(user);
    }
    return acc;
     }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `some` or `find`, this approach uses the function `find`

```js
let owners = [   {     userID: "58c4d7ac",     username: "John.Doe",     firstName: "John",     lastName: "Doe",     email: "John.Doe@acme.com"   },   {     userID: "68c4d7ac",     username: "User2.Name2",     firstName: "User2",     lastName: "Name2",     email: "dh@acme.com"   } ],
    users = [   {     userID: "58c4d7ac",     username: "John.Doe",     firstName: "John",     lastName: "Doe",     email: "John.Doe@acme.com"   },   {     userID: "68c4d7ac",     username: "User2.Name2",     firstName: "User2",     lastName: "Name2",     email: "dh@acme.com"   },   {     userID: "88c4d7ac",     username: "User3.Name3",     firstName: "User3",     lastName: "Name3",     email: "dh@acme.com"   } ],
    result = users.filter(({userID}) => !owners.find(o => o.userID === userID));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```